# which url is used for testing code by GitHub when we push via GitHub actions added to repository?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, github-actions, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I am new to CI/CD pipelines so I tried to integrate GitHub actions for unit testing on my existing app which runs on `xyz.com`. I wanted to make sure if I push code to GitHub which automates unit testing so which `url` GitHub uses to deploy app.

I am using laravel So in env file created for CI/CD GitHub action pipeline what would be APP_URL.

Question came to my mind as code pushed to GitHub will be tested by automated tests via GitHub actions before pushing it to server. Also is it feasible to connect to MySQL database which is on my server which already have data (don't want to use fresh database each time) because its a bit complex to create sample data to be insert to fresh database each time.

Thanks

Sample code laravel test

```
public function test_can_check_password_policy()
    {

        $response = $this->withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'app-version' => 'xyz'
        ])->get('api/password-settings');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertJson([
            'success' => true
        ]);
        $response->assertJsonFragment(['password_uppercase' => '1']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer localhost is used by github actions and it is used in laravel default by `.env.testing` file settings

Answer (score 0):

GitHub does not deploy the app for you, you will need to configure that yourself somehow. For unit testing I would not expect any deployment needed, so it seems you are confusing some topics here. How are you running your unit tests and what errors are you running into? More context will help getting better answers.

As for the database integration question: there are options to do so, but that is best to ask in a new question.

Comment: I am trying to use https://github.com/shivammathur/setup-php/blob/master/examples/laravel.yml so basically what I understood from yml file is it will install php and then install some extensions needed and install laravel via composer use environment file so by deployment I mean github will set php on its own server which uses ubuntu as mentioned in this file.

Comment: Yes database related question could be ask in another thread.

Comment: So what is the actual error you are running into? That will help us trying to help you 

Comment: basically my error is cURL error : Could not resolve host: so what would be host used here. so in laravel host would be from env file as per my understanding

Comment: And from where are you getting that error? Inside running the tests? Can you link to a public repo with an example?

Comment: yes this error comes inside tests? repo is not public so I could not share but if you understand laravel I am pasting some code, hope is helps you. edited sample code in question itself as I could not add that in comment here

Comment: So what would be url for curl request for get method in GitHub that is my question. as code is on GitHub server still not reached to my server and automated tests will run on GitHub server.

Comment: Maybe this is too simple: but isn’t this a matter of configuring it as this during CI? ‘APP_URL=http://localhost’ and the run against that?

Comment: so I am getting new error now for default localhost settings "Failed to connect to localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused" I tried with port localhost:8080 as well that does not work either. trying to figure out what causes that, any idea?